# Virus behaviour but couldn't find any virus on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, virus, characters

I found a strange virus-like behaviour on my PC running Windows 7. I'm not able to type properly with my keyboard. Sometimes it won't respond, and some other times it adds characters indefinitely to the typing area. When I click on the desktop, it creates new folders. When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> on a browser windows, it opens an unlimited number of windows.

I tried with [Kaspersky](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaspersky_Anti-Virus) and [ESET antivirus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESET#Products) trial versions, but I couldn't find any virus.

I don't always get this behaviour, but perhaps 50% of the time...

Comment: Hi, you may want to post this on superuser.com - this isn't the place for this question.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like a hardware problem to me. I'd be keen to try another keyboard before hunting for viruses.

Comment: Even though it happens on clicks as well, I'd still try another keyboard; reboot after you try a new one though.

Answer (score -1):

but When i click on the desktop it creates new folders for each mouse click. It happened once. Anyway i'll try with another keyborad.. and the keyboard is just 1 month old.

Comment: anybody has some idea? It happens with mouse too... when i click on one bookmark folder item, it opens all the bookmarked items.